# Regex to identify Event time received between two specific times with date format

Tags: regex, graylog

I am not experienced with regex. I want to identify all user's in my system who log onto their machine between the times 11pm and 9am(Military time). Although I am not concerned about the date, the program I'm working with(Graylog) requires the date format to be included; this is what I have so far:

EventTimeRecieved = {\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} 13:00:00}:{\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} 21:00:00}

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Regex is a pattern matching, you can't match anything different (**or between**) the pattern you give to it.

Comment: Is it possible to create two seperate rules? For instance, EventTimeRecieved > {\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} 13:00:00} and EventTimeRecieved < {\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} 21:00:00}.

Comment: You can use the Time frame selector. Take a look at the docs, no need to use regex: http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.0/pages/queries.html#time-frame-selector

Comment: Problem with the two separate rule is the comparison operator (eg '>' '<') If you are using regex it matches an string, therefore it can't check against a date value.

Comment: Thanks! this seems to do what I need.

Comment: You will also want to check the natty patterns documentation since it is what graylog uses: http://natty.joestelmach.com/doc.jsp

Comment: And when you find your solution share it with us! Add an answer and mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the time-frame to 'keyword' and specifying the time to 'yesterday 2300hrs to today 0700hrs' did the trick. Thanks @jorge-campos for the help.